# No puedo crear un calendario que se sincronice con Google

Tags: android, api, google-calendar, calendar

Estoy tratando de crear un calendario en la cuenta de Google, he conseguido crear calendarios pero ninguno se sincroniza con la cuenta de Google y no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Creo saber donde está el problema pero no consigo solucionarlo.

el código es el siguiente:

```
public static long createCalendar (Activity activity, String name, String account, boolean local){

        String color = "blue";

        ContentValues calendarvalues = new ContentValues();

        //The account that was used to sync the entry to the device. If the account_type is not {@link #ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL} then the name and
        // type must match an account on the device or the calendar will be deleted.
        if(local) {
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMYLOCAL");
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
        }else{
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account);
            calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account);
        }
        //Local  CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL

        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, name);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.parseColor(color));
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
//        //None          CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_NONE          Cannot access the calendar
//        //freeBusy      CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_FREEBUSY      Can only see free/busy information about the calendar
//        //Read          CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ          Can read all event details
//        //Respond       CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_RESPOND       Can reply yes/no/maybe to an event
//        //Override      CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OVERRIDE      not used
//        //Contributor   CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_CONTRIBUTOR   Full access to modify the calendar, but not the access control settings
//        //Editor        CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_EDITOR        Full access to modify the calendar, but not the access control settings
//        //Owner         CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER         Full access to the calendar
//        //Root          CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_ROOT          Domain admin

        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, account);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);

//        calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_LOCATION, "Spain");


        Uri calUri = null;
        Uri result = null;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            PermissionUtil.requestCalendarPermission(activity);

            return -1;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
        }else{
            calUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        }

        if(calUri != null) {
            if(local) {
                calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMYLOCAL")
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
                        .build();
            }else {
                calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
                        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account)
                        .build();
            }

            result = activity.getContentResolver().insert(calUri, calendarvalues);
        }

        if (result != null) {
            try {
                return Long.parseLong(result.getLastPathSegment());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Creo que el error está en la línea siguiente:

```
calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account);
```

Porque he estado mirando los valores devueltos por la siguiente consulta:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
     calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
}else{
     calUri = Uri.parse(calendarUriString);
}

String[] projection = new String[]{
            CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    //      CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE,
            CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS,
 };

 Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(calUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

id: 1 
Name: My Calendar@Local 
Display name: My Calendar 
access level: 700 
AccountName: My Calendar@Local 
AccountType: com.local 
ownerAccount: Owner Account visible: 1 
sync: 1

id: 2 
Name: test@gmail.com 
Display name: test@gmail.com 
access level: 700 
AccountName: test@gmail.com 
AccountType: com.google 
ownerAccount: test@gmail.com 
visible: 1 
sync: 1

id: 3 
Name: Test Cal 
Display name: Test Cal 
access level: 700 
AccountName: test@gmail.com 
AccountType: test@gmail.com 
ownerAccount: 1 
visible: 1 
sync: 1

He probado con lo siguiente:

```
calendarvalues.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
```

Pero el calendario ni siquiera se crea.

Si alguien sabe como hacerlo o me puede pasar algo de documentación o ejemplos que me sea de ayuda, se lo agradecería.

Comment: Mira la segunda respuesta de este hilo: [Creacion de calendario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977422/how-to-create-simple-calendar-on-android) Tambien este enlace: [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html]

Comment: Hola @Garmael gracias por los enlaces, le he echado un ojo a lo que me has puesto, la guía de Calendar Provider ya la había visto, y del otro enlace hace referencia a crear eventos, pero lo que yo quiero es crear un calendario que se sincronice con la cuenta de Google de forma transparente al usuario (sin Intents en los que el usuario pueda seleccionar nada) para que en cada dispositivo no tenga que crear un nuevo calendario

Comment: He encontrado tambien esto : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065334/sync-android-calendar-with-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065334/sync-android-calendar-with-app) y esto [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036541/data-synchronization-manually-sync-mail-calender-and-contacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036541/data-synchronization-manually-sync-mail-calender-and-contacts)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Garmael probare a ver si con eso funciona